# Could not cast of type Set to Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I've found several threads related to this however none of the solution helped in my case. I have an array `formValues` of type `[String: Any?]`. I then need to get the value from the `Images` key, which works fine with `formvalues["Images"]`. Then I'm casting it to a `Data` array. This return following error: `Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Set<Foundation.Data>' to 'Swift.Array<Foundation.Data>'`

```
let formvalues = self.form.values()
let images = formvalues["Images"] as! [Data]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: The value for key `Images` is a `Set` so cast it to a set:

```
let images = formvalues["Images"] as! Set<Data>
```

---

An error message *Could not cast value of type 'Foo' to 'Bar'* simply means:

- The actual expected type is `Foo`
- You think it's `Bar`
- Trust the compiler and use the **expected** type

PS: If `images` is required to be an array, you have to create one explicitly.

```
let imageSet = formvalues["Images"] as! Set<Data>
let images = Array(imageSet)
```

Comment: I need to cast it as an Array not a Set, since it already is a Set

Comment: It's not possible to cast Set to Array, if you need an array you have to **create** an array **from** the set

Answer (score 0):

Assume your formvalues is a dictionary:

```
let formvalues: [String: Any] = self.form.values()
var images: [Data]?

switch formvalues["Images"] {
case let set as Set<Data>:
    images = Array(set)
case let array as [Data]:
    images = array
default:
    images = nil
}
```